# krb5 and pam_mount

Tags: kerberos

I successfully installed and configured krb5 on a Red Hat 6.4 server, now I can authenticate against an active directory with kerberos.

pam_mount is installed and configured, but it only mounts a cifs share, if I first enter the command

```
kinit username
```

on the host before logging in. Then I make a kdestroy and try it again, but it doesn't mount the share anymore.

So my conclusion is, that there is no kerberos ticket for pam_mount. But why, if I can login with my kerberos account?

this is my **pam_mount.conf.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pam_mount SYSTEM "pam_mount.conf.xml.dtd">
<pam_mount>

<volume fstype="cifs" ssh="0" server="fsamu21.adm.ds.domain.ch" 
path="A_21_Home11$/%(USER)" mountpoint="~" options="sec=krb5" user="*" />

<logout wait="0" hup="0" term="0" kill="0" />

<mkmountpoint enable="1" remove="true" />

</pam_mount>
```

This is my **/etc/pam.d/system-auth**:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_mount.so
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_krb5.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_krb5.so use_authtok
session     optional      pam_mount.so
```

Comment: How are you logging in?

Comment: What does klist -f show you at various points in this process? I'm guessing that you aren't getting forwardable tickets at some point. You can test this with kinit -f . Check the pam section of appdefaults in krb5.conf. Setting forwardable=true and external=sshd may help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be a better fit for unix.stackexchange.com